# Access to the list created on Web Service

Tags: c#, forms, web-services, list

I would like to get the list created on Web Service in my Windows Forms application. The point is, I would like to have the access to the full list and not to have to add every item separately to the new list.

I've searched the Internet and didn't find any useful information for my problem.

I'll be grateful for every help.

EDIT:
I'm adding every item from the Web Service list to the new list like this:

```
foreach (var item in webServiceComarch.zwrocListedoAktualizatora())
                            {
                                ListazWebService.Add(item);
                            }
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please try to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of list its going to be ? List of string or any object of class ? You need to get json and convert it into any list of objects.

Here's a link how to convert json to list of objects.

[Deserialize JSON array(or list) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935343/deserialize-json-arrayor-list-in-c-sharp)